# Get an error Terms and Condition message in checkout payment page After Upgrading to Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-upgrade, terms-and-conditions, error-message

I enable T&C configuration in My Magento 2.3.4 , after i upgraded to Magento 2.4.1. I got this checkout payment page

```
The order wasn't placed. First, agree to the terms and conditions, then try placing your order again.
```

The error message comes from `validateAgreements` function from `vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/Checkout/Plugin/Validation.php` file. In Magento 2.3.4 this file does not being called at all in the checkout payment page, but in Magento 2.4.1 this file is being called in the checkout payment page calling the `beforeSavePaymentInformation`  plugin function which use the `validateAgreements` that triggers the error message

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is super weird thinks. For guest user it's works as expected. Try the following dev:

Step 1: **app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Checkout\Plugin\Validation"
            type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\CheckoutAgreements\Checkout\Plugin\Validation"/>
```

Step 2: **app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model/CheckoutAgreements/Checkout/Plugin/Validation.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\CheckoutAgreements\Checkout\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface;
use Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Checkout\Plugin\Validation as BaseValidation;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;

class Validation extends BaseValidation
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function beforeSavePaymentInformation(
        PaymentInformationManagementInterface $subject,
        $cartId,
        PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
        AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
    ) {
        // no need to check Checkout Agreements validation when set payment method from review step
    }
}
```